# Wordpress: wp-content folder separated from the rest

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to move my wp-content folder in another folder.

For example, this is the wordpress folder:

- "wp-admin" folder
- "public" folder (inside there is wp-content)
- "wp-include" folder
- (other files)

I already followed a guide, so I have:

```
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/public/wp-content' );
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://www.example.com/public/wp-content' );
```

in my wp-config.php

that is right, yes?
but that doesn't seem to work.

The contents of my site are shown (but they were being showed when there weren't those code lines, too) but the themes don't work well.

Do I have to add something else?

Comment: Are you using the default theme of wordpress?

Comment: No, but I tried also with the default theme and it has this problem too

Comment: Try this : `define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname( __FILE__ ) . 'path/to/wp-content' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/path/to/wp-content' );`

Comment: So basically replace $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] with dirname( __FILE__ ) ? That shows me a blank page :(

Comment: Have you try by debugging to see what path is it retrieving ?
And make sure you wrote the same code that I gave you.

Comment: Yes I wrote the same code, but that shows me a blank page, not even my contents without the theme, like before.
How do I debug with wordpress?

Comment: I found this code in a support forum:
<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css.css

Could this work? Where should I put it?

Comment: This one is for `template_directory`. And I don't think it will work.Because our aim is to move **WP-CONTENT**.

Comment: I found [this](http://www.paulund.co.uk/move-wp-content-folder-to-different-location).Try this as well/

Comment: That was the guide I followed. The result is the same.
But I think the only thing that doesn't work is the themes.
Like I said, even if I didn't define WP_CONTENT_DIR and WP_CONTENT_URL, the contents are shown. The theme isn't.

Comment: Okay I have implemented in my localhost and I got it working by little bit of debugging.So I will advice you to do like this:
First do this : `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/public/wp-content'; exit;` And check that path is correct or not.

Comment: I'm sorry where should I write that code? And where will it show me the path?

Comment: Just above the `define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/public/wp-content' );` So it will show you the path on your browser.

Comment: Mmm the path is not correct. Now i'm working on localhost and it shows me this:
C:/xampp/htdocs/public/wp-content

but between "htdocs" and "public" is missing my directory named "wordpresstest" o.O

Comment: So add it like this `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'wordpresstest/public/wp-content';`

Answer (score 0):

If the content is shown, that implies that the definitions you have added to **wp-config.php** are working properly.

Incorrect styling implies that there is a hard-coded path within your theme files. For example, the theme creator used:

```
// Incorrect 
echo '/wp-content/themes/themename/css/stylesheet.css';
```

Instead of...

```
// Correct 
echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/stylesheet.css';
```

Or even an incorrect call to [content_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/content_url).

You'll need to find these hard-coded URLs/paths, and update them to the correct format.